# Issues while trying to insert into database in PERL using DBD::SQLite module

Tags: perl

I am new to Databse. I installed SQLite on my system and tried running PERL program to insert into databse

SQLite commands to create database and table

In command prompt, I iterated to SQlite directory and given commands as

```
sqlite3 one.db;
create table table1 (a int, b string);
```

It created a database and table

I executed the followed PERL program

```
use strict;

use warnings;
use DBI;

use DBD::SQLite;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=one.db","","") or die "cannot 

connect";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO 'table1'
                       (Income, LAST_NAME )
                        values
                       ('1000', 'poul')");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I got the following error

```
DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: no such table: table1 at DBI.txt line 14.
no such table: table1 at DBI.txt line 14.
```

After getting comments from `IKEGAMI`, I changed the `DBI->connect` as

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect

("dbi:SQLite:dbname=C:/Users/nitkumar/Downloads/sqllite/one.db","","

") or die "cannot connect";
```

I started getting error message as

```
DBI connect('dbname=C:/Users/nitkumar/Downloads/sqllite/one.db','',...) failed:
 database disk image is malformed at DBI.txt line 8
cannot connect at DBI.txt line 8.
```

After getting more comments i got the version by using

```
use DBD::SQLite;
warn $DBD::SQLite::VERSION;
warn $DBD::SQLite::sqlite_version;
```

I got the `output` as

```
1.37 at version.txt line 2.
3.7.12.1 at version.txt line 3.
```

I am using `sqlite3` . I guess there are no issues with version

Comment: If this is the reason then it would have printed error msg saying "cannot connect". But it has not given any such error. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Ok. How to give path of the database??. Suppose I have create database in `c://sqlite` folder

Comment: Nit: `b text` makes more sense than `b string`

Comment: What version of DBD::SQLite are you using? `perl -MDBD::SQLite -e 'print $DBD::SQLite::VERSION'` And what version of the SQLite library is DBD::SQLite using? `perl -MDBD::SQLite -e 'print $DBD::SQLite::sqlite_version'` [A mismatch between DBD::SQLite and the command line client could cause the `database disk image is malformed` error.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=775209)

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Comment: A separate issue - you don't need the `use DBD::SQLite` line. The DBI modules loads the correct DBD automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`one.db` is probably not the path to the database you created from the command line.

If you ask to open a non-existent database, it creates it. Just like the command line tool does.

For example, if the path to your database is `c:\sqlite\one.db`, you can use

```
"dbi:SQLite:dbname=c:\\sqlite\\one.db"
```

or probably

```
"dbi:SQLite:dbname=c:/sqlite/one.db"
```

Comment: I tried but it is giving another message saying           DBI connect('dbname=C:/Users/nitkumar/Downloads/sqllite/one.db','',...) failed:
 database disk image is malformed at DBI.txt line 8
cannot connect at DBI.txt line 8.

Comment: Nitesh: does deleting and recreating the table help?

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue/question.  Corrupted by ASCII transfer of binary file??? Version incompatibility??? What's `$dbh->{sqlite_version}` and the version of your SQLite used by your client?

Answer (score 3):

I expect the `one.db` that you created is not the same `one.db` that your Perl script is trying to access.  Make sure the `one.db` that you created is in the same directory where you are running your Perl script *from*.

DBD::SQLite will create the database file if it does not exist, so what is likely happening is you created `one.db` in one directory, and then are executing your Perl script from another directory, creating a second `one.db` in that directory.

I typically do my SQLite table creations within my Perl scripts so that there is no guesswork and I can easily blow my db file away at a later point and everything will just automagically work:

```
$dbh->do(q[
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
        a int,
        b string
    )
]);
```

Also, you will find things work better if you specify an absolute path for your db file.  You could create it relative to the `$ENV{HOME}` directory or the script's directory.  I would recommend the latter:

```
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$Bin/one.db","","")
```

Finally, use `RaiseError`!  Writing boilerplate to check if there was an error is a waste of your time, and you're always going to forget something.  So, do this:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$Bin/one.db","","", {RaiseError => 1});
```

Then you can stop doing all those `or die ...` checks.